# Arduino for statement error. Expected ')' before ';' token. How to fix this?

Tags: c++, arduino, led

I am relatively new to Arduino and C++ and I am stuck on this error. I am trying to have LEDs streak across a matrix at the same time.

The error message I receive is

> "exit status 1. expected ')' before ';' token"

Any help would be great.

```
#define NUM_LEDS 64
#define DATA_PIN 3
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  for ((count1 = 0; count1 <= 15; count1++) and (count2 = 31; count2 >= 16; count2--)) {
    leds[count1] = CRGB::Blue;
    leds[count2] = CRGB::Blue;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(100);
    leds[count1] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[count2] = CRGB::Black;
  }
}
```

Comment: `for` condition syntax is completely invalid.

Comment: you might want to review the syntax for `for` loops. Can you explain how yours is supposed to work?

Comment: for (count1 = 0, count2 = 31; count1 <= 15 && count2 >= 16; count1++, count2--) { } will fix it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop doesn't work.

A `for` loop is: `for` ( `initial`; `test`; `update` )

You have all of those three parts twice with an "and" between them, that is invalid syntax.

`for ((count1 = 0; count1 <= 15; count1++) and (count2 = 31; count2 >= 16; count2--)) {` <- Invalid!

What you can do is this:

`for (count1 = 0, count2 = 31; count1 <= 15 && count2 >= 16; count1++, count2--)`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems in your provided code (like not defining your variables - I'm assuming, however, that you have merely not provided all relevant code). The main issue is your "for loop" syntax, which you may want to look like this:

```
#define NUM_LEDS 64
#define DATA_PIN 3
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}

void loop() {
  for (count1 = 0; count1 <= 15; count1++){
    for (count2 = 31; count2 >= 16; count2--) {
        leds[count1] = CRGB::Blue;
        leds[count2] = CRGB::Blue;
        FastLED.show();
        delay(100);
        leds[count1] = CRGB::Black;
        leds[count2] = CRGB::Black;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i would be careful with assuming what OP actually wants when they dont explain it clearly in their question. Your fix is one possible interpretation, but how do you know that OPs code **should** look like this?

Comment: ...also I would not tell someone that they should use macros to define constants when there are better alternatives. I know that this is just 1:1 copied from the original code, but when you say "should look like this" you are putting the bar quite high yourself

Comment: Noted, have removed eluding to clarity about what the questioner is after.